# $f_n \to f$ implies $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{x \in A_n} f_n(x) \to \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $A_n:=\{ -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^n}, \cdots , 0, \cdots, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2} \}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ and $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is a dense subset of $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$.

Think of a sequence of functions $\{ f_n : A_n \to \mathbb{C} \}$ such that
\begin{equation}
f_n \to f
\end{equation}
pointwise on $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ as $n \to \infty$, where $f :[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a smooth function.

Now, I want to establish the limit
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{x \in A_n} f_n(x) \to \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x)dx
\end{equation}
as $n \to \infty$.

What additional conditions on $f_n \to f$ do I need in order to establish this limit of the sum and integral? This turns out to be much trickier than expected...Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Why $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$? If I understood the definition of $A_n$ correctly, we have $A_2=\left\{-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{4}, 0, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}\right\}$, and $A_3=\left\{-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{6}, 0, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}\right\}$, and therefore  $A_2\not\subset A_3$.

Comment: oops, I will correct this.

Comment: Uniform convergence (assuming $f_n$ are themselves continuous) is enough. Just pointwise is nowhere enough: $f_n \equiv_{A_{n - 1}} f$ is enough to get pointwise convergence, but still allows us to get arbitrary sum in left part.

Comment: For a concrete example of why pointwise convergence is not sufficient, let $f \equiv 0$, and for all $n$, $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}2^n &x = \frac 12 - \frac1{2^n}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Then $f_ n \to f$ pointwise, but $\frac 1{2^n}\sum_{x\in A_n}f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$, while $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(x)\,dx = 0$.